# Vite - output to a dist folder keeping src folder immediate child folders only

Tags: configuration, vite

I am using Vite to build my project.
When Vite outputs the built files they should be structured in a particular way as the production application does not allow subfolders besides the ones that are a first child.
The way my src folder is structured:

```
src/
├── assets/
│   ├── images/           <- each child folder can contain files or other folders
│   ├── fonts/
│   ├── icons/largeIcon.png 
│   ├── someFile.js       <- files can be contained directly
│   └── ...
│
├── config/               <- We can have many immediate child folders in src 
│   ├── app-config.json
│   ├── api-config.json
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

When building the folder structure should be flat after the immediate child folders in src:

```
out/
├── assets/
│   ├── largeIcon.png 
│   ├── someFile.js       <- and any other file contained in child folders
│   └── ...
│
├── config/               
│   ├── app-config.json
│   ├── api-config.json
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

Is this achievable solely with Vite configuration?

What I was able to do is to use `rollup-plugin-copy` and list each src -> dist relation but that is going to be a maintaining hell.